# PostgreSQL enum default failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an enum type with default value as the following:

```
app_type apps_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'undeployed'::apps_status
```

But now whenever I try to insert I get an error app_type cannot be empty. Also when you continue trying you will get error: `Number has already been taken.`
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Apparently Rails sends a NULL value (instead of the keyword `DEFAULT` or simply omitting the column)

Comment: But the same rails app works with MySQL.

Comment: MySQL is known to replace values without telling you (or to allow nulls in non-null columns)

Comment: Wow but how can I solve the problem now, so the app will work across both DBs?

Comment: Don't send a `NULL` value, or remove the column alltogether from the insert, or use the `DEFAULT` keyword. All that will also work for MySQL

Comment: @zulq: it's primarily a bug in ActiveRecord (and other ORMs, for that matter). Which should be reported as such to them.

Comment: Please always show the exact text of error messages, it helps. Pg version is always good too.

Comment: Forgot to mentioned that PG version is 9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped. However after thorough research I realized that PostgreSQL ENUM doesn't support default but domains do so I use domain instead. Domain is working fine and is inserting default value as well.
See the following link:
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/create_user_defined_type

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `NOT NULL` constraint, which is filled by the ORM, and not deferrable.

First off, try setting the value to `DEFAULT` on the ORM side.

If it's not a workable solution in your ORM, try adding a trigger that sets the default value:

```
create function make_default() returns trigger as $$
begin
  new.app_status := 'undeployed'::apps_status
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger before insert or delete on yourtable
for each row when (new.app_type is null)
execute procedure make_default();
```

If that doesn't work either, drop the `NOT NULL` constraint altogether, and enforce it with a constraint trigger instead:

```
create function reject_row() returns trigger as $$
begin
  raise exception 'rejected!'
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create constraint trigger after insert or delete on yourtable
for each row when (new.app_type is null)
execute procedure reject_row();
```

Comment: Something like `before_validation :initialize_stuff, :if => :new_record?` (where the `initialize_stuff` method would set the initial value if needed) combined with a validation to ensure that it is set should do the trick.